# Why is Snackbar alert displaying like toast alert on my desktop Maui app?

Tags: c#, maui, desktop, snackbar

I setup a snackbar alert like this:

```
var snackOpt = new SnackbarOptions
{
  BackgroundColor = Colors.Red,
  TextColor = Colors.Yellow,
  CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10),
  Font = Microsoft.Maui.Font.SystemFontOfSize(20)
};

var snackbar = Snackbar.Make(msg, null, "", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), snackOpt, lblPassList);
await snackbar.Showspkdfj[();
```

lblPassList is the name of a label on the screen where I want the snackbar alert to show. But what is happening is the message is showing up in the lower right corner of my computer screen> And the background color is grey and the text color is black. I purposely selected the strange colors to see if it would really work.

Why is the snackbar alert appearing in the corner of my computer screen and not where I'm telling it to anchor?

Comment: You may try using a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) to customize the alert.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/alerts/snackbar?tabs=android#details-of-implementation-and-limitation-for-different-platforms)

> Native" Snackbar is available only on Android and created by Google. Other platforms use "Container" (UIView for iOS and MacCatalyst, ToastNotification on Windows).

> Snackbar on Windows can't be anchored to VisualElement and is always displayed as a default Windows Notification.